# Any Help on retrieving information from one app into another one?

Tags: android

### There is a digital address android app that provides a person digital location

I want to click a button in an android app I am building which fetches my digital 
the location from the digital address app into a TextView I have created in the Android app I am building.

Comment: Seems like [ContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics) would come in handy - build it into the digital address app and access via uri from other app.

Comment: You'd better thank @Andy

Comment: @Andy Sorry i mistook edited name for you. Thank you very much for your answer.